# How to know which class implemented the interface?

Tags: java, interface

(Java beginer)

I've one stupid doubt.

Here is the code

```
XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
```

XPathFactory is absrtact class, How object is getting created ? Any connection here ?

```
XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();
```

XPath is an interface, so when xpathFactory.newXPath() is called Does it returns the object of class who has implemented XPath interface ? Is it correct ?

How can we know which class implememnted XPath interface ?

Can anyone help me to understand this ?

Thanks

Comment: did you try `xpath.getClass().getName()` ?

Comment: Generally with factory patterns like the ones you list above, the reference type for the returned object is an interface, but the object itself will likely be assignable from some specific class implementing the interface (a little trickier and less common when an anonymous class is returned instead). A simple invocation of `getClass` on the object will tell you that.

Answer (score 0):

First, it doesn't matter - all that matters is that some class does (it might be an anonymous inner class). Second, you can use `getClass()` to find out. Like,

```
System.out.println(xpath.getClass().getCanonicalName());
```

Answer (score 0):

It gives you instance of *some implementation* of `XPathFactory`, which in turn provides you with an instance of *some implementation* of `XPath`.

You can get info about the actual implementation through `getClass()`, but the point is - you should not care. That's what interfaces are for - to hide the actual implementation used and only give you the *contract* to rely upon.

Comment: so can I say that the concert class of XPathFactory and class who has implemented XPath interface is same ...?

Comment: No  you cannot. It might be true, but you'll never know unless you check through `getClass()`. And even then, there's no guarantee that it will be the same on another computer with different JVM settings. The point is that you should not assume anything other than what the interface (contract) tells you.

Comment: Is that possible two different class implementing same abstract class ...? Because if if it’s not the same class (according to last comment) then it could be the case am thinking.

Comment: It is indeed possible for two different classes to extend the same abstract class. It's also possible for a class to implement two different interfaces, or for a single class to extend an abstract class and implement a different interface. It's *not possible* for a single class to extend two unrelated abstract classes though.

Answer (score 0):

`XPathFactory.newInstance()` is a `static` method. It can't return an instance of the `XPathFactory` base class itself (since it's abstract), but it can return an instance of some sub-class of `XPathFactory`.

`xpathFactory.newXPath()`, as you said, returns an instance of a class that implements the `XPath` interface. You don't have to care which actual class was instantiated (that's an implementation detail), but you can obtain that information by calling `xpath.getClass()`.